# Error when trying to import the Crypto package

Tags: python, image-processing, encryption, pip

When I issue these import commands:

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
```

I see this error message:

```
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/image-encryption-main/PyImgEnc.py", line 4, in <module>
        from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

These are the libraries I installed:

```
pip install wheel
pip install scipy
pip install pbkdf2
pip install pyaes
pip install pycryptodome
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, have you installed the correct crypto module?

Comment: I have installed following libraries:
pip install wheel
pip install scipy
 pip install pbkdf2 pip install pyaes pip install pycryptodome 
but it doesn't work. What module should I install?

Comment: What do you not understand about the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'"? If you don't have the module installed, you cannot load it.

Comment: Thats what I'm asking how can I install this module because I have tried a lot of things.

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade `pip` to `latest version` before executing the commands:

1. `pip uninstall crypto`
2. `pip uninstall pycrypto`
3. `pip install pycryptodome`
4. `pip install pycryptodomex`

This worked for me.

Comment: Solved the issue for me, thanks

Comment: nothing solve my problem.